# How should I handle failure between API calls

Tags: rest, api, design-patterns, architecture

I have encounter a problem where a action can be done through either a sequence of existing Http requests like the following:

```
api1() -> api2() -> api3()
```

Or I will have to create a new API that does it at once so its something like:

```
apiNew() {
   api1();
   api2();
   api3();
}
```

Then I will just send request to apiNew() and let it do all of the three functions.

However, since all three apis involves database change, each individual API is wrapped with a transaction block.

Here is the problem, in case I call them separately. Then if `api1()` succeed but `api2()` failed, the database is in some `in the middle` state which will require manual change, so it can move to the correct state.

The way I am doing it now is to create the `apiNew()` and wrap all three in the same transaction block so all the database changes are going under the same transaction.

I am just wondering, is there some other way of doing this type of work, so I can reuse `api1()` `api2()` and `api3()` in a way that it does the error handling correctly without rewrite the code to a single API call.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [distributed transationcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_transaction) and [two-phase commit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol).

Comment: @LutzHorn Thanks for the reply, I actually read about two-phase commit when tried to implement transaction in mongoDB, but distributed transaction is something new to me. I will give it some reasearch :) .

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without an actual transaction but by remodelling your API and database and using [idempotency keys](https://brandur.org/idempotency-keys).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am talking a look at this. And another solution I found is to use saga but with saga the implementation can get quite complicated and I will need to add the saga infrastructure on top of the existing apis. This one does look more promising and I will you know if its good for my implementation.